# How to append list items from another list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to update a list which is having one dictionary to multiple dictionaries based on the loop

ex:- i have one list it has to update as per given range

Input :

```
"_items": [
            {
                "text": "Hi.",
                "feedback": "",
                "_score": 0
            }
        ]
```

i used

```
for i in range(0,5):
     json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

While using this i'm getting `list index out of range` error

Expected out put :

```
"_items": [
            {
                "text": "Hi.",
                "feedback": "",
                "_score": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "Hi.",
                "feedback": "",
                "_score": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "Hi.",
                "feedback": "",
                "_score": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "Hi.",
                "feedback": "",
                "_score": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "Hi.",
                "feedback": "",
                "_score": 0
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Your input is not a dict or JSON, are you missing the outermost brackets? `{ "_items": [...] }`

Comment: Yes i didn't added that part

Comment: Please, always try to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that easily with list comprehension :

```
data = [
          {
            "text": "Hi.",
            "feedback": "",
            "_score": 0
          }
        ]
new_data = [item for item in data for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate multiple replicas of the same element in a list, you can simply do:

```py
n=5
item = [{'text': 'Hi.', 'feedback': '', '_score': 0}]
items = item*n
```

This will result in a list of n identical dictionaries.